# Go Fish Deck and Matches

Tags: c, arrays

```
void analyzeHand(char* usrInput[], Card*deck) {
    int a;
    int y;
   int x;
   int ret;
    int f;

printf("What rank do you think the computer has based on your hand?\n");
scanf("%c",usrInput);

for(y=5;y<10;++y) {

if(usrInput[0]==deck[y].faces) {
        ++takencard;
        f=y;
        deck[f];
```

The problem I'm having is trying to store the value of the index y every single time there is a match. For example if the the usrInput matches the 5th and 8th index I want to store both 5 and 8. The reason for this being is that I would transfer the matches to the users hand by creating a function that will take those specific elements in the array and remove them from the computer's hand.

Another problem arises as well for me. I'm not sure how to modify it so that the hand of the player or computer has their card removed if the the opposing player guesses a match correctly. I tried using pointers, and tried manipulating it by making the matches if found in the users  or computers hand equal to NULL. I was considering using linked lists to do so but I was wondering if there were other possible alternatives that don't involve an overhaul of my code just yet. If I need to include more of my code since I included only a snippet, let me know.

Comment: `scanf("%c",usrInput);` type mismatch.

Comment: Are you suggesting I change the format? It's correct, and the function executes fine with that statement.

Comment: No, it is not correct. `"%c"` has to be matched with `char*`, not `char**`. You should enable the compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: `char* usrInput[]` --> `char usrInput[]`. I can not tell in just a part of the code.

Comment: char*usrInput[0];
    analyzeHand(&usrInput,deck); that is the int man section of the code, which is why it's %c and not &%c, I've printed out the index for each match  correctly but I need to be able to store the values without them overriding one another if a match is found.

Comment: `char*usrInput[0];` is bad.

Comment: You write _I want to store both 5 and 8_ and _I would transfer the matches to the users hand by creating a function that will take those specific elements in the array and remove them from the computer's hand._ Don't make your life harder than necessary by splitting your program into functions where this only imposes complicated data transfer; instead, match, take and remove the cards within one loop.